# Need more help Android Eclipse Java script for simple click counter

Tags: android, eclipse

I need this app to do a simple click counter here is my java script for MainAvtivity.
I set a Button and TextView but for some reason when I run it on my emulator nothing happens when I press the button. If someone has time to walk me through I'm willing to give you my email address.
Please help :(

this is MainActivity:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



int TextView = 0;
TextView text;

public void count1(View v){
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            TextView++;
            text("count " + TextView);

        }
    });


}



protected void text(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {



    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

 }
```

Question: what am I doing wrong? >:((((

Comment: What do you want that button to do?

Comment: Just start from the activity.. Don't jump to fragment at the first..
You need to follow a book. It will be better to learn many thing for you. Keep on trying.. Best of luck..

Comment: I wanted to make a simple click counter using eclipse Android developer's Kit. Very simple starting count from 0 and every time you press the button it adds +1. The issue is also that I need to make sure the fragment_main.xml is synced with the main activity window. let me know if you have suggestions or can help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
text.setText("Count " + TextView);
```